# Calling database handler class in a python thread

Tags: python, database, multithreading, mariadb

I'm programming a bit of server code and the MQTT side of it runs in it's own thread using the threading module which works great and no issues but now I'm wondering how to proceed.

I have two MariaDB databases, one of them is local and the other is remote (There is a good and niche reason for this.) and I'm writing a class which handles the databases. This class will start new threads of classes that submits the data to their respected databases. If conditions are true, then it tells the data to start a new thread to push data to one database, if they are false, the data will go to the other database. The MQTT thread has a instance of the "Database handler" class and passes data to it through different calling functions within the class.

Will this work to allow a thread to concentrate on MQTT tasks while another does the database work? There are other threads as well, I've just never combined databases and threads before so I'd like an opinion or any information that would help me out from more seasoned programmers.

Comment: You must not have the same connection thread being used in two different threads.

Comment: So start a new connection at the start of every thread?

Answer (score 0):

Writing code that is "thread safe" can be tricky.  I doubt if the Python connector to MySQL is thread safe; there is very little need for it.

MySQL is quite happy to have multiple connections to it from clients.  But they must be *separate* connections, not the same connection running in separate threads.

Very few projects need multi-threaded access to the database.  Do you have a particular need?  If so let's hear about it, and discuss the 'right' way to do it.

For now, each of your threads *that needs to talk to the database* should create its own connection.  Generally, such a connection can be created soon after starting the thread (or process) and kept open until close to the end of the thread.  That is, normally you should have only one connection per thread.

Comment: I'm coding server software for IoT devices, this code takes information from a MQTT server, and puts it into a database. There's a lot of stuff going on in the background, and the code connects to an external database, however, if the database goes down, the script records to a local database then detects when the main db is up and recovers automatically like nothing happened. I'm just not very experienced with MySQL/MariaDB so having a bit of issue but the MQTT thread has to be separate and start other DB threads so the computation of the data doesn't hold up the MQTT handling.

Comment: @SamuelArchibald - In web-based apps, each user connection (insert row, run report, etc) is a separate thread, hence necessarily a separate connection to MySQL.  I am not familiar with MQTT; sounds like it works differently?

Comment: Thank you for the information, MQTT is a common IoT protocol that allows entities to connect and authenticate, then publish and subscribe to a topic based system. (ie, publishing to "devices/1" will make all devices or code subscribed to the topic see the message posted) So MQTT doesn't have anything to do with the database itself, my code acts as the middleman between MQTT and a database and adds a bunch of extra features.

Comment: @SamuelArchibald - OK, then I need to better understand the "client" that interfaces with MySQL.  Is your Python code?  Or some package that uses python?  Does MQTT send things via a "queue" and your single process then acts on?  What advantages are there of multi-threading here?  Etc.